# How to pass slash(/) as search string in Angular Front End to Back End

Tags: angular

i am having a search operation in Angular page. In that have entered the search text as "/" (slash) in the  search text box. But i got the error as below

url: "http://localhost:10322/app/**/ER**

i got double slash due to that its failed to call backend. please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: show us the code

Answer (score 0):

Encode the search text:

```
encodeURIComponent(str)
```

Comment: when i tried encodeURIComponent() the special character /  has been converted to %2F. now i got 400 error